# Numerical method to find stationary solution of an PDE in the phase space

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, python

I'm relatively new in numerical methods for PDEs, so I have a question about solving the following PDE numerically for $W(x,p)$ in the phase space:
$$-p\frac{dW}{dx}+x\frac{dW}{dp}+\frac{d}{dx}\left(xW \right)+2 \frac{d}{dp}\left(pW \right) + \frac{d^{2}W}{dx^{2}} +\frac{d^{2}W}{dp^{2}}-\frac{d^{2}W}{dxdp} = 0.$$
What is the simplest (yet reasonably accurate) numerical method to solve the equation above? I expect to see a Gaussian in $x,p$ and I wish to visualize the numerical solution in the window $(x,p,W(x,p))$.

Comment: If a Gaussian is expected as a solution then why not assume a Gaussian with some free parameters $p_i$, plug it into the equation and form a residual $R(p_1, p_2,...)$.  after that solve numerically R=0.

Comment: thanks for the comment. This is only a test problem. Later I would like to solve a nonlinear PDE. Assuming that we didn't know that it is Gaussian, how would we solve it numerically?

Comment: Well, we have here a linear differential operator. If we replace the derivatives by finite-difference then this will become a linear algebra problem for the discretized function W, $\hat{A} \vec{W} = \vec{r}$. The right-hand side is not zero in general since it accounts for boundary conditions. This is the simplest general direction, but for details you'd need to read some basic book on solving PDEs by finite-difference.

Comment: But what if the PDE is nonlinear, say with a term like $\frac{d^{2}}{dpdx}(x^{2}W)$? Will finite-difference still work?

Comment: What you wrote is still linear. But for a nonlinear PDF finite-difference would still work except you'd end up with a system of nonlinear equations rather than with a linear system. Solving a system of nonlinear equations is much more difficult than solving a linear system, and there are no theorems of uniqueness and existence etc. There you'd likely need to introduce real or pseudo time stepping or something like that to let the system relax to the steady state solution. Sometimes the physical meaning of your equation can guide you. Good luck.